# Unable to set 'Data Model used in view' field when creating a new view in a 2sxc app

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc, dnn9

I am trying to create a listings app for Persons in 2sxc. I've managed to create an app, add a content type with fields then when creating a view for the listing, I am unable to set the 'Data Model used in view' field to 'list of content items' (or anything for that matter) and it gives me a 'There was an error in form calculations. Please report this to Admin' error

['There was an error in form calculations. Please report this to Admin' error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWrOW.png)

Answer (score 0):

The message isn't ideal.

I believe the problem is that you specified you want a list of items, but then didn't select the content-type (for the items you would want to show on this template). If you set that, you should be fine.

Comment: The error message still appeared with content item set. However this may have been a bug associated with version 12.02.1 as with the latest install of 12.04 this issue has been resolved.